# problems with waiting for multiple deferred function calls to finish

Tags: jquery, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the [node-facebook-sdk](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk) to make FB graph API calls using Node.JS

I want to get feed data from all of a users friends.
FB graph API only allows 50 friends per batch request, so I am making a series of batch FB.api() calls.

I am trying to store the FB.api() calls in an array, then using jQuery when() to call the deferred functions.

## problems:

1) the function I pass to the .done() function is executed prematurely.
2) the console.log(feed) is executed after .done(), which to my knowledge shouldn't happen.

```
$ = require('jQuery');


//maximum batch size request is 50. use 2-D array to store in buckets of 50 friends each.
                var numFriends = friends.data.length;
                var batch = [];
                var deferred = [];//array to hold all the requests
                var feed_dump = [];//where we collect all the feed data

            //initialize a bucket for each set of 50 friends
            for (var i = 0, ii = numFriends / 50; i < ii; i++) {batch.push([]);}

            //put corresponding requests in in buckets.
            for (var i = 0; i < numFriends; i++) {
                batch[Math.floor(i/50)].push({ method: 'get', relative_url: friends.data[i].id + '/feed?since=' + '-1 month'});//not sure if the date format will work user.last_updated
            }

            //make the multiquery request for each bucket
            for (var i in batch) {
                var bucket = batch[i];
                //nested FB api call

                deferred.push(FB.api('', 'post', {'batch' : bucket}, function(res){//res = array 50 friend feeds
                        if (!res || res.error) {
                            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error); return;
                        }
                        for (var j in res) {
                            var feed = JSON.parse(res[j].body);
                            console.log(feed);
                            feed_dump.push(feed);//feed for each friend appeneded to dump
                        }
                }));
            }

            console.log('this should show up before graph api requests are made.');

            //jQuery when() function.
            $.when.apply(null, deferred).done(function() {
                console.log('hopefully feed_dump has been updated...');
                PySocket.emit('update_user_graph',JSON.stringify(feed_dump));
            });
```

How can I defer the batch FB.api() requests properly? Also, if someone can think of a better way to do this, please let me know; I am not that experienced with async javascript.

I guess a simpler form of my question is : how can I wait for multiple callback functions to finish?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: shouldn't you wrap what you push in "deferred" in a function, so it gets only called by $.when.apply ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** Encapsulated callback count decrement : http://jsfiddle.net/3L9zc/32/

```
function BatchAPICalls(){
    var calls = [];
    var self = this;

    self.push = function(){
        var args = [];

        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length - 1; i++)
            args.push(arguments[i]);

        calls.push({
            fn: arguments[0],
            callback: arguments[arguments.length - 1],
            args: args
        });        
    };

    self.start = function(callback){
        var callbacksLeft = calls.length;

        function batchCallback(){
            callbacksLeft--;
            if(callbacksLeft == 0)
                callback();
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < calls.length; i++){

            var call = calls[i];

            var batchItemCallback = function(){
                call.callback.apply(this, arguments);
                batchCallback();
            };

            call.fn.apply(this, call.args.concat([batchItemCallback]));            
        }
    };
}



var numFriends = friends.data.length;
var batch = [];
var feed_dump = [];

for (var i = 0, ii = numFriends / 50; i < ii; i++) {
    batch.push([]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < numFriends; i++) {
    batch[Math.floor(i/50)].push({ 
        method: 'get', 
        relative_url: friends.data[i].id + '/feed?since=' + '-1 month'
    });
}

function done() {
    console.log('hopefully feed_dump has been updated...');
    PySocket.emit('update_user_graph',JSON.stringify(feed_dump));
}    

var batchCalls = new BatchAPICalls();

for (var i in batch) {
    var bucket = batch[i];

    batchCalls.push(FB.api, 'call #' + i, 'post', {'batch' : bucket}, function(res){

        if (!res || res.error) {
            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error); return;
        }
        for (var j in res) {
            var feed = JSON.parse(res[j].body);
            console.log(feed);
            feed_dump.push(feed);//feed for each friend appeneded to dump
        }
    });
}

console.log('this should show up before graph api requests are made.');

batchCalls.start(done);
```

Comment: in my old code, the functions didn't execute when i added them to the deferred array (I set a breakpoint after populating the array and waited awhile).

Comment: well as I see, the FB.api call is async, therefore there is no guarantee that it is executed immediately, but the call is made.

Comment: right - so the $.when() call is just a wrapper for a simple function with a callback. But I'm trying to find if there is a way to wait for the callbacks of the FB.api() calls to finish.

Comment: @ejang : Please let me know if my new solution works (see edits)

Comment: the counter decrement is a hackish method - I was looking for a more elegant approach, perhaps wrapped in a library. where would the checking mechanism for watching the counter take place? If I use a while() loop, it blocks the system. If I use setInterval, I run the risk of waiting longer than I should.

Comment: I assure there is not blocking taking place here : the FB.api calls are made async and when there callbacks are executed, my "custom" callback gets executed... but yes, this should be encapuslated, but it's not so hard to accomplish

Comment: Encapsulated callback count decrement (proof of concept :  http://jsfiddle.net/3L9zc/32/ )

Comment: @ejang, is it you who -1'd me ?